# Any way to open images in a larger window?

Tags: support, markdown

Is there any way to make images that are included in a Q & A open in a larger view when either clicked on or hovered over? Some times I need to post a larger image than will fit, but I don't want to necessarily have a large image take up a lot of space in the normal view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a smaller image in your post and link to the larger image.

With images uploaded to Stack Exchange's imgur server (as they should), you can add `s` or `m` to get a smaller image.

```
[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFhbRm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFhbR.jpg)
```

[image]

You can also specify `width` and `height` attributes in the `img` tag to perform arbitrary resizing. If you specify only one, the aspect ratio is kept.

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFhbR.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFhbR.jpg" width="200" height="100"></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any risk in doing it like this? `[![ss of nmon][4]][4]`? Seems to work on this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105908/how-to-display-meminfo-in-megabytes-in-top/105933#105933

Comment: @slm What risk do you envision?

Comment: I was thinking there might be issues with the renumbering of links that the editor does for you if you insert another link above this one. I can try, but wasn't sure.

Comment: Just tried and it breaks the numbering if you try and put something in front of a link that includes `[![ss of nmon][4]][4]`.

Comment: @slm Oh, well, I don't use the numbering. Just use the direct URL form and the editor won't bother you.

Comment: Yeah I'll just have to adapt to doing that way instead. Thanks for the tip.